# Projeto não abre no Visual Studio (load failed)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, iis, wcf, binding

Depois de abrir **uma vez o VS2013 em modo de administrador**, um projeto na minha solução não é aberto. A solution é da empresa onde comecei a estagiar e não sei quase nada do código. O erro é visível na imagem a seguir:

1 - VS em modo de administrador:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2 - VS em modo normal:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu já tinha aberto esse projeto, que tem serviços web, fiz publish do projeto no IIS (versão 10), corre tudo bonitinho em **localhost:82/Services**, os serviços (WCF) estão disponíveis nos outros projetos sem problemas (os que estão publicados no IIS continuam a correr bem). Já mudei o **< UseIIS >** para **false** como vi em alguns posts, mas não resolveu (apesar de conseguir abrir o projeto uma vez depois de alterar essa opão). De salientar que a solução foi feita em VS2010. Deixo o .csproj em baixo:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>
    </ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{C020D666-8F1A-4D1F-85B8-25C18658F7E5}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>BusinessServicesImplementation</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>BusinessServicesImplementation</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
    <FileUpgradeFlags>
    </FileUpgradeFlags>
    <UpgradeBackupLocation>
    </UpgradeBackupLocation>
    <OldToolsVersion>4.0</OldToolsVersion>
    <UseIISExpress>False</UseIISExpress>
    <IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication />
    <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication />
    <IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>

    <PackageAsSingleFile>false</PackageAsSingleFile>
    <DesktopBuildPackageLocation>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\pack\BusinessServices</DesktopBuildPackageLocation>
    <PublishDatabases>true</PublishDatabases>
    <FilesToIncludeForPublish>OnlyFilesToRunTheApp</FilesToIncludeForPublish>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Serialize.Linq, Version=1.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=25bcc11ba213b377, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Inspirennovit\Serialize.Linq.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.Entity" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.EnterpriseServices" />
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization" />
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel" />
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Transactions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.ApplicationServices" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.DynamicData" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Entity" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Mobile" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Services" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="AccountContactsService.svc" />
    <Content Include="AddressesService.svc" />
    <Content Include="AlertsService.svc" />
    <Content Include="BaseService.svc" />
    <Content Include="BusinessServicesImplementation.Publish.xml" />
    <Content Include="CAEService.svc" />
    <Content Include="CompaniesService.svc" />
    <Content Include="ContentViewsService.svc" />
    <Content Include="CPVsService.svc" />
    <Content Include="EDesk.svc" />
    <Content Include="eDeskService.svc" />
    <Content Include="ForumManagerService.svc" />
    <Content Include="FavoritosService.svc" />
    <Content Include="JobsService.svc" />
    <Content Include="MaterialAPCMCService.svc" />
    <Content Include="MaterialAppImagesService.svc" />
    <Content Include="MaterialApplicationService.svc" />
    <Content Include="MaterialCaseStudyFileService.svc" />
    <Content Include="MaterialCaseStudyService.svc" />
    <Content Include="MaterialCatalogueService.svc" />
    <Content Include="MaterialCertificationService.svc" />
    <Content Include="MaterialCPVService.svc" />
    <Content Include="MaterialDeclarationService.svc" />
    <Content Include="MaterialImagesService.svc" />
    <Content Include="MaterialObjectService.svc" />
    <Content Include="MaterialService.svc" />
    <Content Include="MaterialTechnicalSpecService.svc" />
    <Content Include="MaterialUNSPSCService.svc" />
    <Content Include="MenuService.svc" />
    <Content Include="NetworkService.svc" />
    <Content Include="NewsService.svc" />
    <Content Include="ProductsService.svc" />
    <Content Include="ProjectsService.svc" />
    <Content Include="PublicContestService.svc" />
    <Content Include="SchedulesService.svc" />
    <Content Include="StatisticsService.svc" />
    <Content Include="TracerServiceGen.svc" />
    <Content Include="UserNotesService.svc" />
    <Content Include="UsersService.svc" />
    <Content Include="Web.config">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Web.Debug.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Web.Release.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="AccountContactsService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>AccountContactsService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="AddressesService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>AddressesService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="AlertsService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>AlertsService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="BaseService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>BaseService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="CAEService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>CAEService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="CompaniesService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>CompaniesService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="ContentViewsService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>ContentViewsService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="CPVsService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>CPVsService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="EDesk.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>EDesk.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="eDeskService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>eDeskService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="eRequests.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ForumManagerService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>ForumManagerService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="FavoritosService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>FavoritosService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IAccountContactsService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IAlertsService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IContentViewsService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\ICPVsService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IFavoritosService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IForumManagerService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IFileService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IMaterialAPCMCService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IMaterialAppImagesService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IMaterialApplicationService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IMaterialCaseStudyFileService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IMaterialCaseStudyService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IMaterialCatalogueService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IMaterialCertificationService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IMaterialCPVService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IMaterialDeclarationService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IMaterialImagesService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IMaterialObjectService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IMaterialService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IMaterialTechnicalSpecService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IMaterialUNSPSCService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\INetworkService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\INewsService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IProductsService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IProjectsService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IPublicContestService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\ISchedulesService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IStatisticsService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\ITracerServiceGen.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IUserNotesService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IUsersService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IRequest.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IBaseService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IAddressesService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\ErrorList.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>ErrorList.resx</DependentUpon>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\ICAEService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\ICompanyService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IGrlTableService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IJobService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IMenuServices.cs" />
    <Compile Include="JobsService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>JobsService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MaterialAPCMCService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MaterialAPCMCService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MaterialAppImagesService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MaterialAppImagesService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MaterialApplicationService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MaterialApplicationService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MaterialCaseStudyFileService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MaterialCaseStudyFileService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MaterialCaseStudyService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MaterialCaseStudyService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MaterialCatalogueService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MaterialCatalogueService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MaterialCertificationService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MaterialCertificationService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MaterialCPVService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MaterialCPVService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MaterialDeclarationService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MaterialDeclarationService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MaterialImagesService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MaterialImagesService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MaterialObjectService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MaterialObjectService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MaterialService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MaterialService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MaterialTechnicalSpecService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MaterialTechnicalSpecService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MaterialUNSPSCService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MaterialUNSPSCService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MenuService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MenuService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="NetworkService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>NetworkService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="NewsService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>NewsService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="ProductsService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>ProductsService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="ProjectsService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>ProjectsService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="PublicContestService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>PublicContestService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="SchedulesService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>SchedulesService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="StatisticsService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>StatisticsService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="TracerServiceGen.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>TracerServiceGen.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="UserNotesService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>UserNotesService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="UsersService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>UsersService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="App_Data\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\BusinessManagers\BusinessManagers.csproj">
      <Project>{331F9029-FF8E-4302-B170-E10E3928C6A9}</Project>
      <Name>BusinessManagers</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DataLibrary\DataLibrary.csproj">
      <Project>{703D677D-23D7-47CA-8EBF-E134BCF2422F}</Project>
      <Name>DataLibrary</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Utilities\Utilities.csproj">
      <Project>{AE5A8453-1E18-471E-9C6E-23A948975162}</Project>
      <Name>Utilities</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Interfaces\ErrorList.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>ErrorList.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="ClassDiagram1.cd" />
    <None Include="Properties\PublishProfiles\Profile1.pubxml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>False</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>82</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl>http://localhost/Services1</IISUrl>
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>
          </CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

Comment: Muda essa linha aqui `<DevelopmentServerPort>82</DevelopmentServerPort>` para `<DevelopmentServerPort>8200</DevelopmentServerPort>`

Comment: Mas esta alteração não implica que todos os serviços vão passar a correr na porta 8200?